# How do I render/route a component for individual Topic without nesting it in existing component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Okay, I'm trying to setup routes based off this guide: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

The second example has a list of Topics that you can select, each with its own "route" to the Topic component for that specific topic, but my problem is that it's just rendering the Topic component underneath the list of Topics. How do I get ONLY the Topic to render to the page? I want the list of available topics to disappear.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  useRouteMatch,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/topics">Topics</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/topics">
            <Topics />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return <h2>Home</h2>;
}

function About() {
  return <h2>About</h2>;
}

function Topics() {
  let match = useRouteMatch();

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Topics</h2>

      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${match.url}/components`}>Components</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${match.url}/props-v-state`}>
            Props v. State
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      {/* The Topics page has its own <Switch> with more routes
          that build on the /topics URL path. You can think of the
          2nd <Route> here as an "index" page for all topics, or
          the page that is shown when no topic is selected */}
      <Switch>
        <Route path={`${match.path}/:topicId`}>
          <Topic />
        </Route>
        <Route path={match.path}>
          <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

function Topic() {
  let { topicId } = useParams();
  return <h3>Requested topic ID: {topicId}</h3>;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define the topic route on the "main" `Switch`.

You will also need to add `exact` prop to `/topics` `Route` to avoid matching `/topics/1` and remove the nested routes inside `Topics`

```js
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/topics">
    <Topics />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/topics/:topicId">
    <Topic />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

```js
const Topics = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Topics</h1>
    <Link to="/topics/1">Topic 1</Link>
    <Link to="/topics/2">Topic 2</Link>
    <Link to="/topics/3">Topic 3</Link>
  </div>
)
```

```js
const Topic = () => {
  const { topicId } = useParams()

  return <h1>{topicId}</h1>
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.